# How to mock this service variable in karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have this scenario

Component part

```
constructor( private serviceA: ServiceA, private serviceB: ServiceB) {
      this.anotherVariable = this.serviceA.config.ABC
}
```

Spec part

```
const ServiceAStub = {
    config: {
        ABC: '1',
    },
};

describe('Component', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
    let appconfigService: AppConfigService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [Component],
            providers: [
                { provide: SerciveA, useValue: ServiceAStub },
                { provide: SerciveB, useValue: {}},
            ],
        }).compileComponents();    
    }));

beforeEach(() => {    
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;    
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create the component', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Running this spec returns error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ABC')
```

how can I mock this so it let it pass?

Comment: Could you please try to add the `async` keyword to the second `beforeEach` like in the first one? I'm not sure, if it helps, its just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try below versions:

**spec file -**

```
const ServiceAStub = {
    config: {
        ABC: '1',
    },
};

describe('Component', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
    let appconfigService: AppConfigService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [Component],
            providers: [
                { provide: ServiceA, useValue: ServiceAStub },
                { provide: ServiceB, useValue: {}},
            ],
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;    
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create the component', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

**comp file -**

```
 constructor( private serviceA: ServiceA, private serviceB: ServiceB) {}
 
 public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.anotherVariable = this.serviceA.config.ABC;
 }
```

If you still face issues then please put your working code over `stack blitz` and share.